# How do I avoid long loading time with custom cell in a UITableView when using a big database

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In the app I'm working on, I have to fetch and use data (text and images) from a quite big database, and, when **load** the tableview, the app freezes for **2-5 seconds**. This is probably going to ruin the **UX** as the **UI** doesn't feel quick to respond to an action.

I think that the **problem** is the presence of many **images** (not really heavy, `50x50px`), which are one for each custom cel, and there are about **1000**+ rows.
What I need is to know which is the **best way** to **avoid** this **long loading time**, or how to hide it.

The user opens the *tableview* clicking on a button, which perform a segue, and then I fetch data in `viewDidLoad()`. As I figured out, the `viewDidLoad()` method can block interaction until it's finished. Inside viewDidLoad() I call a function called `fetchCard()`. It puts in an array the `Card` object, which contains the properties I use in the cells (name, thumbnail image).

```
func fetchCard() {

    cards = []

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Card")
    let sorter: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: sorterParameter , ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.predicate = definitivePredicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sorter]
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = true

    do {
        let results = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        cards = results as! [Card]
    } catch {
        print("Fetch failed: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Is there a way to load, for example, only the visible rows, and *would this work*/*is it a good practice* to do that? Are there better ways?

P.S.: To avoid a discussion based on personal preferences, for "better" I mean the way with the highest performances in terms of loading speed.

EDIT: Added code example.

Comment: Are you using CoreData for local storage? Can you provide some sample code of how you fetch data?

Comment: google for asynchronous coding

Comment: @haluzak yes, i'm using core data, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Have you added indexes to the table? What is large, 1K, 10K, 100k? Are all the images different or many the same?

Comment: I fetch about 1100 objects. Images are unique for each cell.

Comment: What is the row count in the database? But there are only a few images at any one time displayed, correct? You are using reusable cells?

Comment: Again: Have you added indexes to the table for the sort column? How many rows in the Core Data? Are there joins?

Comment: @zaph yes, there are just 8 images displayed at time, and yes, i'm using reusable cells

Comment: with indexes you mean a lateral column of letters like in the contacts app? No, I haven't implemented that yet.

Comment: No, data bases can have indexes on columns which speed up sorting and searching, otherwise each row must be examined.

Comment: When you state: "I fetch about 1100 objects." you mean as each cell needs an image you only fetch that image? That all 1100 are only fetched if the user scrolls the tableview through all 1100 images?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91524/discussion-between-qubex-and-zaph).

Comment: If you have a Core Data performance problem you need to study both Core Data and SQL data bases in general. It might take a day to get a basic understanding, I've spent many weeks studying SQL databases. Look into indexes, in your case `sorterParameter` is probably a prime candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what the OP has stated the problem solution is to create an index on the attribute (column) that is being used by the sore.

See this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935348/what-does-the-indexed-property-of-a-coredata-attribute-do) for some more information. Then follow up with the Core Data docs or a good Core Data book.

Notes:
1. The If the table row count is around 1000 as the OP has hinted the access time with an indexed Core Data should be almost instantaneous.

2. The time to regenerate an image of 50 x 50 pixels is should also be trivial.
3. On performance issues it in important to measure where the performance issue is otherwise time and effort is spend on the wrong areas.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're loading many data in viewDidLoad() method and you are not loading them asynchronously on background thread. When you call fetchCard() in viewDidLoad() you block loading of the whole screen until loading from DB is done.

To load data on background thread you will have to do this:

```
let queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)
    dispatch_async(queue, { () -> Void in
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parentContext = moc

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Card")
        let sorter: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: sorterParameter , ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.predicate = definitivePredicate
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sorter]
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = true

        do {
            let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            cards = results as! [Card]
        } catch {
            print("Fetch failed: \(error)")
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            tableView.reloadData()
        })
    })
```

Also if loading from CoreData gets slow you will have to find out why. It might help to add indexes to variables in objects which you sort/filter by. In `sortDescriptors` you add 1 descriptor, try to index the `sorterParameter` which is used in the descriptor.

If you have images stored in CoreData database, it might be wise to load them asynchronously as well to keep the scrolling of tableview smooth. You can use similar code as before, just move the image loading inside the GCD block and set the image to the imageview in main thread ('`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`...').

Comment: I tried your code, but it still takes too much time to load data from Core Data, as I see the tableview empty, and after a while it crash. I'll look for indexes and database: can you point me to a reference about indexes?

Comment: I'll make the images to async load, too

Comment: @Qubex_ Consider the OP's statement: "takes too much time to load data from Core Data". Is it really an async problem? Not that an async should not be used, just that it is not the current performance problem.

Comment: @zaph it looks like, as you suggested, that I have to use indexes. I didn't know about them, and I'm reading now the other answer you linked.

Comment: @zaph as I mentioned it would definitely help to add indexes to appropriate variables to speed the whole search in database, I'll try to help Qubex on the chat he provided

Answer (score 1):

UITableView already only loads visible cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Assuming you're reusing cells, your problem is most likely in loading the data, not displaying it.

Take a look at Apple's sample project for asynchronous loading: [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Resizing a large image to fit a smaller table view cell size image does take some processing power and a decent amount of IO. If possible, you should use smaller thumbnail images for the table view, rather than large images. Though, it may take a significant size image to notice this on newer devices.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm going to try to implement that

Comment: @Qubex_ The Core Data access should be quick, first you need to find out what is slow: Core Data of the imaging. You need to measureand get the times.

Comment: @Marcus The images are 50 x 50 so that is not very large.