# How is the fastest way to make relation in core data from a attribute?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on a performance optimization in a sync algorithm.

Currently, an iOS app receive a massive JSON from a Web API.
In many cases there are attributes related to a relationship, for instance:
PS. It's a simplified example.

```
[
    {
        "name":"Alice",
        "age": 18,
        "key": "a001"
    },
    {
        "name":"Bob",
        "age": 18,
        "key": "b002",
        "parent":"a001"
    },
]
```

Given the model in CoreData:

[image]

After downloading the JSON I need to save it into Core Data. However, I need to make the relationship between such objects.

Currently, I'm searching the object on the coredata and making the relationship, how can you see in the example below (PS. It's a simplified example):

```
@IBAction func newItemTap(_ sender: Any) {

    if let context = self.managedObjectContext {
        let newPerson = Person(context: context)
        newPerson.name = "Alice"
        newPerson.age = 18
        newPerson.key = "a001"
    }

}

@IBAction func secondItemTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if let context = self.managedObjectContext {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key = %@", "a001")
        do {
            if let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject] {
                if results.count > 0 {
                    let newPerson = Person(context: context)
                    newPerson.name = "Bob"
                    newPerson.age = 18
                    newPerson.key = "b002"
                    newPerson.parent = results.first as! Person?
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error reading trips")
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func checkTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if let context = self.managedObjectContext {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")
        do {
            if let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Person] {
                for obj: Person in results {
                    print(obj.name ?? "")
                    print(obj.parent?.name ?? "<no parent>")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error reading trips")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a fast way to make the relationship as shown in secondItemTap method.

Has someone faced and solved this kind of performance problem? Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really well versed in `CoreData`, so I cannot provide actual code, but basically it will boil down to the following:

Make sure that your database maintains a good index on your `key` attribute.

Depending on your database there might be different ways to define this in `CoreData`, but judging from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935348/what-does-the-indexed-property-of-a-coredata-attribute-do) it really seems to boil down to just putting a checkmark at the `indexed` property of your data definition (which is pretty close to how it should be).

Comment: It's not the point. The indexes are optimised. I'm looking for a good strategy to do it.

Comment: If your indexes are anything like 'optimised' I cannot see `secondItemTap` being slow. However this might depend on your database, but something like a local SQLite should easily cover your needs (given they are somewhere in the 100 ms range which seems reasonable for a tap). If you have problems beyond that you should be more specific about them.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you want to optimize the speed for the same operation and you are concerned that fetching from the context each time is time consuming. This could be solved by doing the indexing of information yourself.

Let's assume you DO NOT have a copy of json in your CoreData, then you have to create each managed object and inject it into context, in order to void searching for it later on you could keep a dictionary of type:

```
[String: ManagedObject]
```

and keep all the injected objects there. There would be little memory overhead since you just keep the reference to those manage objects.

In the first round you create all the objects and also keep a copy in dictionary of type we mentioned above.

in the second round, you iterate through the dictionary and make the relationships.

In case you already have a copy of json in your code data and would like to update it with this large json, then you would need to fetch the data from core data and then update it.

Comment: I've already used the strategy with dictionaries. However it alloc too many memory.

Comment: No it does not, the dictionary holds a reference to the managed object as oppose to copying the entire object, keep in mind in swift objects are by refernce vs. the structs which are by value. you just copy the address into dictionary so there is very little memory overhead.

Comment: Not in this sample but in my real app does.